# Implicit conversion sequence

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

[N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) §13.3.3.1 [over.best.ics] says:

> The sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in
>   Clause 4 [...]

However, clause 4 defines the following list of the conversions:

- Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
- Array-to-pointer conversion
- Function-to-pointer conversion
- Qualification conversions
- Integral promotions
- Floating point promotion
- Integral conversions
- Floating point conversions
- Floating-integral conversions
- Pointer conversions
- Pointer to member conversions
- Boolean conversions
- Integer conversion rank

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    operator int()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

A a;

int b = a; //User-defined conversion sequence applied

int main() { }
```

As long as user-defined conversion doesn't belong to a set of standard conversions, there is no any standard conversion being applied in the example. So what is the sense of the quote I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the quote you omitted might be illuminating:

> §13.3.3.1/1 An implicit conversion sequence is a sequence of
>   conversions used to convert an argument in a function call to the type
>   of the corresponding parameter of the function being called. The
>   sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in Clause
>   4, **which means it is governed by the rules for initialization of an
>   object or reference by a single expression (8.5, 8.5.3).**

Clause 4 does indeed talk about this.

> 3 An expression `e` can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and
>   only if the declaration `T t=e`; is well-formed, for some invented
>   temporary variable `t` (8.5).
>
> 6 The effect of any implicit conversion is the same as performing the
>   corresponding declaration and initialization and then using the
>   temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The result is an
>   lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to
>   function type (8.3.2), an xvalue if `T` is an rvalue reference to
>   object type, and a prvalue otherwise. The expression `e` is used as a
>   glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.

The "full set of such conversions" (listed in Clause 4) refers to standard conversions. Remember that it says standard conversion sequences can be empty. Then §13.3.3.1.2 describes user-defined conversion sequences. It consists of:

- A standard conversion sequence
- A user-defined conversion
- Another standard conversion sequence

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not quite clear. The Standard defines a well-formed explicit conversion sequence a bit later as one of the following froms: _a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1)_, _a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2)_, or _an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3)_.

Comment: Or you meant the _implicit conversion sequence_ and the _sequence of conversion_ appeared in the quote I cited is a bit different things, did you?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv From what I understand a standard conversion sequence *is* a implicit conversion. I was clarifying that "implicit conversion as defined in Clause 4" refers to the paragraph where it talks about "*implicitly converted*".

Comment: Ah, that's it wasn't a definition of the sequence of conversion, but a clarification about clause 4, was it?